# Making a mistake by not using .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Microsoft web application architecture related...

Wondering if I'm making a mistake by not using .Net's MVC for my new web application? I started out web development in ASP Classic and have moved forward with each iteration of ASP.net. I've monkeyed around with ASP.net MVC the past few months and just didn't like certain parts of it. I like routing, razor, and the idea of view specific models. But it just seemed like my apps were getting overly complex after adding a few functionalities--I feel the same is true when I look at the MVC versions of apps like nopCommerce and Umbraco compared to their prior versions.

I went back and basically started writing a .Net Website/MVC hybrid. I created my own base class for "view models" that implemented Data Annotation validation; a Simple Mapper to bind form submissions to the models and to map entity properties to model properties and vice versa; created extension methods and helpers for things like paging, checked, selected, and even/odd; use controls like Repeaters, Literals, and standard HTML tags with `runat="server"` that don't require view state.

This approach seems to allow me to have the best of both worlds, keeps my "Controller" code close to the "View", and everything works in Medium Trust.

Here is some sample code:

```
public partial class Admin_Users_RoleAdd : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected class RoleAddModel : BaseModel
    {
        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public override bool Validate()
        {
            if (base.Validate() && Cortex.DB.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == Name))
                Errors["Name"] = "Already in use";
            return Errors.Count == 0;
        }
    }
    protected RoleAddModel model = new RoleAddModel();
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form["Submit"].HasValue())
        {
            SimpleMapper.FormMap<RoleAddModel>(model);
            if (model.Validate())
            {
                var entity = new Role();
                SimpleMapper.Map<RoleAddModel, Role>(model, entity);
                Cortex.DB.Roles.AddObject(entity);
                Cortex.DB.SaveChanges();
                Response.Redirect("Roles.aspx");
            }
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

And the "View":

```
<h1>Add Role</h1>

    <div id="MainForm" class="form">
        <%= model.GetErrorMessage("Error") %>
        <form action="<%= Request.RawUrl %>" method="post">
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="Name">Name</label> <%= model.GetErrorMessage("Name") %><br />
                <input type="text" name="Name" value="<%: model.Name %>" class="required" maxlength="100" />                
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="Description">Description</label> <%= model.GetErrorMessage("Description") %><br />
                <textarea rows="8" cols="40" name="Description" maxlength="250"><%: model.Description %></textarea>             
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create" class="primary" />
                <a href="Roles.aspx">Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Are there things I will regret about this approach later? The main thing I can think of at the moment is test-ability, but the VWD Express doesn't support it anyway.

Comment: `VWD Express doesn't support it anyway` - not from within the IDE, but you can use NUnit anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've done that in the past. It will only work with a compiled .dll though, correct? I've been developing my app as a Website so I'm not sure it will work unless I put all my helpers and stuff into a separate assembly and run tests against that (but then I think my mapper will break in Medium Trust since it would be using Reflection across assemblies).

Comment: @Sam: you realize you will have to select 5 correct answers :)))) Because there is no right answer, but opinions. Its like asking whether C# or Java is better ... **Right tool for the right job** is the answer. Select, but carefully, but select :)) Good luck with ASP MVC, you gonna love it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like Microsoft's implementation on MVC; the use of magic strings, that it seems somewhat backward to say the action then the controller, that it's like having to learn a dozen new language because it's full of microsolutions (routing, razor).

I dislike it so much so I started to write my own, but the more I wrote, the more I realized it was inflexible and the more I fixed this, the more like the Microsoft implementation it looked.

After hours and hours and hours of development on essentially a crap version of MVC, I ditched it. I've started to go back over design documents and code and write over (or at) the top of them

**WRITE LESS CODE**

I rewrote the UI tier of my crappy MVC app to the MS MVC in about eight hours. I'd been working on it for about eight weeks before that. Granted most of the thinking had already been done so it may not have been that quick to write an MVC from scratch.

Almost everything I used was out of the box, except the AuthorizeAttribute class, which just didn't do what I wanted it to do.

Why this relevant to your question?

It's a mistake to write code when you don't need to. If you have tried and tested libraries, reuse them, if you don't then look for them from a trusted source before writing your own. None of my problems are new and I doubt none if any of yours are too. They've all been solved by people who have more resources at their disposal than most of us.

Part of this realization that I should stop reinventing wheels and just code what doesn't come prepackaged is I'm working on a migration project at work, with Lawyers discussing the finer points of IP relating to some encryption routines. We're going to need to spend weeks writing some code to translate data to another format because we can't 'give away' our IP that was used to secure the data. If the app was just written with canned libraries, it would just be the data and the encryption keys we'd need to hand over. It would be done by now rather than a tenth draft for the lawyers to discuss.

Comment: Same here, I used http://T4MVC.codeplex.com and magic strings are part of history. Not a single one in the app.

Answer (score 2):

A good, well-written, maintainable and solid application is that, regardless of the technologies used to develop it. You can write good code and bad code with any language or framework. With time we gain tools that make our lives as developers easier, but if you are a good developer to begin with, it doesn't matter which MVC framework or XML parser you happen to be using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever works for you.  If you're the sole developer, and always will be, and you deeply understand the way you're doing development, then go for it.

Most methodologies are about improving long term maintenance.  Maintenance accounts for as much as 95% of the overall cost over a programs lifetime.

But by mixing architectures, you could be setting yourself up for incompatibilities that may be difficult to fix due to impedance mismatch between architectures.

I'm a little confused as to why you wrote your own model binders, when MVC's model binding works just fine.  Or why you felt the need to do your own data annotation validation.  But regardless, it's your code.

If you don't like MVC, you might consider using something like fubumvc, or spring.net

Comment: Some of the things I didn't like were probably just failing to understand how things worked. Routing is great if your app works as intended; I wanted users to be able to specify custom friendly URLs without including ids or requiring Controller/Action as part of it. I could stick a wildcard URL at the end, but couldn't figure out how to make it the first rule, then fail over to the other routes. Things like AutoMapper required more than Medium Trust. 20MB+ of libraries to support WebAPI, JSON, etc. To be honest, with where I am now it wouldn't be too difficult to port.

Comment: Oh, and I wrote my own model binders and data annotation validation because this isn't an MVC app and I wanted to easily extend the validation of the view models to include things like unique name checks. I know I can create new Data Annotation attributes, and probably will if things get repetitive, but sometimes it is quicker and easier to override the base class's validate method.

Comment: @Sam - ASP.NET 4.5 includes model binding and validation support for Webforms.

Comment: Cool, wasn't aware of that. Will have to check it out. Now all I need is for shared hosts to get their acts together an install .Net 4.5! :) Do you happen to know how many of the other DLLs are going to end up in the GAC as opposed to being NuGet'd in everybody's applications? Right now the size of a simple app with all the necessary libraries is a turn off.

Comment: @Sam - More or less, anything that isn't part of the BCL will probably be done via NuGet.  Bin deploying has the fewest number of problems, and allows apps with different versions of the same framework to coexist peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the companies I've been involved in or have colleagues at, the trend is they're all moving from classic ASP to writing .Net WebForms at the very least, and the ones doing .Net WebForms are now moving to MVC!

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer for this one.

The only answer coming to mind goes like this: *right tool for the right job*.

My personal opinion though is classic ASP.NET is very much day before yesterday. Yes, they abstract the HTML from you, but hey, there's a reason they started all this MVC project - people (professionals) weren't satisfied with writing web as classic application, no control over rendering, no structure. Plus MVC takes into account and from all modern web technologies that came after classic ASP.NET. Ruby on Rails is a good example - DRY & COC principles. MVC pattern also makes your app much more structured and provides nice separation of concerns...

**Right tool for the right job**